# Automatically enable systemd services installed using deb?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, services, deb

I'm building a bunch of services to install on my own (automatically created) servers. I'm migrating from upstart on Ubuntu 14.04, where services are enabled by default (we have to do extra work if we don't want then to start when installed), to Ubuntu 16.04 where we want to use systemd as the new native service framework.

The services are installed using deb packages that I'm creating myself. I've upgraded the deb creation by adding `--with systemd` to `rules` and adding a `package-name.service` with a systemd unit specification.

The problem I found is that even if I add an `[Install]` section with `WantedBy=multi-user.target`, the service will not be started on the system.

Instead, the service gets installed and then `systemctl status package-name` shows:

```
● package-name.service - My Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/package-name.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I don't have any systemd overrides in my `rules`, which as I've understood from the [Debian packaging with systemd page](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/pkg-systemd/Packaging) as well as the [dh_systemd_enable man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/dh_systemd_enable.1p.html) I can use to *not* enable services if I choose not to.

Also from the looks of the status display it appears that `dh-systemd` did enable the services (the vendor preset bit), but that was not enough. What am I missing?

Comment: I've worked around the problem by calling `dh_systemd_enable` (to make the service run by default) and `dh_systemd_start` (to actually start it after installation) manually from the `override_dh_auto_install` target in `rules`, but I still don't understand why it doesn't get called automatically - as promised in its documentation.

Comment: I haven't worked with `.deb` packages, but I have worked with custom `.rpm` packages that I wanted to enable a service for. With `rpm`s there's a `post` section, which will just run the commands in it after install is finished. That's where I threw in a `systemctl enable`. I assume `.deb` has something similar.

Comment: dpkg has a somewhat more sophisticated (complicated, some may say) way to handle such actions - though you can always just right a trigger script in like in RPM. My comment above was about using this setup - the `dh_auto_install` step gets translated by dpkg-build into a trigger script. My question is more about how to setup SystemD so it enables and starts "vendor enabled" services automatically. For now I'll just post that comment as an answer and approve that :-)

Comment: You need 3 things:  `rules` to contain `dh $@ --with systemd`, `control` to contain `Build-Depends: dh-systemd`, `postinst` to contain `#DEBHELPER#` and a reasonable current build system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've worked around the problem by calling dh_systemd_enable (to make the service run by default) and dh_systemd_start (to actually start it after installation) manually from the override_dh_auto_install target in rules, so it looks like this:

```
%:
    dh $@ --with-systemd

override_dh_auto_install:
    dh_auto_install
    dh_systemd_enable || true
    dh_systemd_start || true
```

Comment: For me, with the `--with-systemd` the default has always been to enable + start anyway, so you should not have to do it manually. sduthil answer's makes more sense. However, your `postinst` script may be missing the `#DEBHELPER#` (See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423069/postinst-maintainer-script-stops-systemd-unit-file-from-starting-automatically-o/423078)

Comment: `--with systemd` is enabled by default in compat modes 10+  https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/debhelper.7.en.html

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you don't need to add anything in `override_dh_auto_install`.

You need `--with systemd` (without the dash between `with` and `systemd`) in the `rules` and the package `dh-systemd` installed.

Comment: This *is* the correct answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't an answer to my issue - I've done that but the result is that the service is in installed but not enabled and not running. Overriding `dh_auto_install` to call `dh_sysyemd_enable` and `dh_systemd_start` is the best way I could find except writing a postinst script manually.

Comment: `--with systemd` is enabled by default in compat modes 10+  https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debhelper/debhelper.7.en.html

Comment: It just doesn't work in version 12 (status shows `Active: inactive (dead)` after installation)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue as well.  It turns out that `dh_systemd_enable` has certain expectations about the content of a `foo.service` file.

You can see this in lines 187-215 of [deb-systemd-helper](https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/xenial/main/all/init-system-helpers/1.29ubuntu1/file/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper).

In particular, ensuring that the `foo.service` file has an `[Install]` section and has at least an `Alias` field where the alias does NOT equal `foo.service` will cause the call to `deb-systemd-helper enable` to detect the needed service.  If you want the service to be automatically started adding `WantedBy=multi-user.target` is also needed.

Below is a lightly modified version of my `foo.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=foo service, foos
After=bar.service
Requires=bar.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/my/script/foo
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
Alias=foo
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I was able to determine this by enabling a couple debug flags and adding debug statements in the `deb-systemd-helper` perl script.  On an Ubuntu 16.04 system I found it here: `/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper`.

So repeatedly running the following and adding debug statements got me to the bottom of the problem.

`$ sudo DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE=1 _DEB_SYSTEMD_HELPER_DEBUG=1  deb-systemd-helper enable foo.service`

Comment: It looks like the `Alias` line causes `deb-systemd-helper` to create a link to `/etc/systemd/system` - which is not necessarily what I want. Can you show what you have in `rules` other than `%: dh $@ --with-systemd` to get your service auto-enabled and started?

Comment: Why don't you want a link in /etc/systemd/system? I believe this is core to the mechanism of enabling a systemd unit.
e.g.

    `$ sudo systemctl disable <redacted>
    Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/<redacted>.`

    `$ sudo systemctl enable <redacted>
    Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi- 
    user.target.wants/<redacted> to /lib/systemd/system/<redacted>.`

Comment: I definitely want a link to `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants`, but I definitely do not want a link in `/etc/systemd/system` - that directory is saved for user managed scripts - for example I have an `apache2` service running on my machine by default, it does not have a link in `/etc/systemd/system`. Setting `Alias=foo.service` will cause deb-systemd-helper to create an alias to my service by adding a link from `/etc/systemd/system` to the real service file - like the `ssh.service` on my Ubuntu box has an alias `sshd.service` so I can use both names. This shouldn't be a requirement.